# Error in MySQLi insert_id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to get the registry id inserted in the database using MySQLi insert_id but it is giving error.

I already researched the web but found nothing that solved this problem.

Where am I going wrong?

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $data = date('d-m-Y');
    $hora = date('H:i:s');
    $id_motorista = $_POST["id_motorista"];
    $km = $_POST["km"];
    $valor = $_POST["valor"];
    $placa = $_POST["placa"];
    $posto = $_POST["posto"];
    $litros = $_POST["litros"];

    $photo_user_origem = $_FILES["photo_user"]["tmp_name"];
    $photo_user_destino = "photos/".md5(time()).".png";

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "banco");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO abastecimentos (dia, km, posto, litros, placa, valor, id_motorista) VALUES ('$data','$km','$posto','$litros','$placa','$valor','$id_motorista')";
    $stm = $conn->prepare($sql);

    //ERROR SHOULD BE THERE STARTED HERE
    if ($stm->execute()){
        $id_bastecimento = $conn->insert_id;

        $stm->close();

        if (move_uploaded_file($photo_user_origem, $photo_user_destino)){
            $sql_update_photo = 'UPDATE abastecimentos SET photo_usuario = ? WHERE id_bastecimento = ?';
            $stm = $conn->prepare($sql_update_photo);
            $stm->bind_param("si", $photo_user_destino, $id_bastecimento);
            $stm->execute();
        }


        $retorno = array("retorno" => "YES");
    } else {
               $retorno = array("retorno" => "NO");
           }

    echo json_encode($retorno);

    $stm->close();
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Does it save In the database

Comment: What error is displayed?

Comment: @MichaelO. The data is stored in the database. Only in the part of sending the photo to the bank does he give an error as if he had not taken the id of the last record of the bank to update the photo.

Comment: __Do not__ write codes in comments, edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44356196/edit

Comment: before going any further https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @BonfimJunior Whats the error?